# Android check if remote server is online

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am new to Android programming and I have been facing problems that didn't exist in native Java. When I run this code in my computer, it runs correctly. But, when I run it in my device.I get nothing, I even tried to post the message to UI and there's no logcat for this. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
                try{
                    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
                    Log.i("TAG","Socket connected");    
                }catch(IOException e){
                    Log.i("TAG","Socket not connected");
                }
```

Update 1: I just changed the code..nothing much and realized that after 2 minutes or so it does what it was supposed to do?? Is is anything to do with keep alive flags? Or is there anyway that I can run the code just for a second or two and stop it. Please understand that the code below the socket creation line executes only after 2 minutes if the server is dead. Here below is my code:

```
    try{
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);   
//Line below executes with no delay
postToUI("Trying to connect to standalone server" + "\n\n");
socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
//Line below executes after 2 minutes
postToUI("Successfully connected to standalone server" + "\n\n");

}catch(ConnectException e){
    postToUI("Socket not connected");
}catch(IOException e){
    postToUI("Socket not connected");
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443166/android-how-to-check-if-the-server-is-available

Comment: It talks about alive host. In which case even if the server application is not listening but, if server host is alive then it will be good. In my case i want to find out if my server is accepting connection.

Comment: It looks like some error is thrown. Try looking for it in the logs or replace `IOException` with `Throwable`.

Comment: If you are getting neither log message in LogCat, then you are not executing the code you have shown above.

Comment: @CommonsWare the code just before the try block is executing.

Comment: Then one of those log messages will be in LogCat, or you will get a "force close" dialog due to an unhandled exception and that stack trace will be in LogCat. Particularly on the one in the `catch` block, please add the exception as a third parameter to the `i()` call, so you see the stack trace.

Comment: Like i said..i got exception just after couple of minutes...i am not sure...what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have done very few Andrioid development so don't bite me *smiley*.

**Possible reasons why the host might not communicate with the client**

- Host has firewall which might be closing the connection (unlikely)
- Host might have unexpectly shutdown e.g power failure (unlikely)
- Host might not properly port forwared (possibly)
- Your andriod app doesn't have the proper manifest that allows the use of sockets.
- Your andrioid device you are testing on might have its internet disabled which can enabled easily.
- Host's address could have changed if it is dynamic.

For logcat, I think that logcat only displays log messages for the main thread. But I am unsure.