# determine aplication is connected to server or not

Tags: java, android, api

I am developing one application which is connecting to server to get some data.
In this I want to check first if application is connected to server or not. And then, if server is on or off?
 Based on the result I want to do my further manipulations.

So how do I get the result of server status?

Here is the code which I am using:

**Code:**

```
try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://192.168.1.23/sip_chat_api/getcountry.php");

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {
 }
```

Comment: look at this class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining session cookies is best choice here, please see how to use session cookie: [How do I make an http request using cookies on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678630/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-using-cookies-on-android)

here, before sending request to server, check for session cookie. If it exists, proceed for the communication.
**Update:**
The Java equivalent -- which I believe works on Android -- should be:

InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut)

Comment: is there any simple method to know about server is active or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443166/android-how-to-check-if-the-server-is-available

Comment: yeah once it will work for me i will accept but may be i need little more help

Answer (score 1):

Check getStatusLine() method of HttpResponse

any status code other than 200 means there is a problem , and each status codes points to different problems happened.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html?is-external=true

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getStatusCode()