# Android ping to server doesn't work

Tags: android, networking, network-programming, ping

I have created an app that pings my server when the app starts to check if it's online (this happens in a new thread) but it always says that my server is offline. The same happens with google.com and 8.8.8.8,.. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
System.out.println(executeCmd("ping -c 10 -w 1 vanlooverenkoen.be", false));

public static String executeCmd(String cmd, boolean sudo) {
    try {

        Process p;
        if (!sudo)
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        else {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", cmd});
        }
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String s;
        String res = "";
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            res += s + "\n";
        }
        p.destroy();
        return res;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

this was another try: Didn't work out:

```
            Process mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
            int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
            System.out.println(" mExitValue " + mExitValue);
            if (mExitValue == 0) {
                System.out.println("0");
                Snackbar.make(mLoginFormView, "Er kan verbonden worden met de server", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            } else {
                System.out.println("else");
                Snackbar.make(mLoginFormView, "Er kan geen verbinding gemaakt worden tussen uw appraat en de server", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
          }
```

Comment: yes I have done that

Comment: What's the exact message you're getting?

Comment: just that the host is not reachable, 1 packet send, 0 recieved, 100% loss

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443166/android-how-to-check-if-the-server-is-available

Comment: I have done that two, doesn't work

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren I presume you have added internet permissions to your app. Isn´t it?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> this are all the permissions i have added to my app

Comment: Real device or emulator?

Comment: I am using an emulator