# How to reconnect with socket after server power failure from Android Client

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I have a `server` program in `python` which sends and receives `data packets` to and from `android client`. I am using `TCP` with `sockets` in `android client` to communicate with `python` program. 
Every thing is working fine but when the `server` is shutdown with an NSF power failure it disconnected from `client`.

My Question is how I check for the availability of the server all the time using `android` services or any `BroadcastReceiver` or inside my `MainActivity` when `socket` closed or disconnected. 
I don't want to restart my `client application` again after `server` power failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For those with the same issue.**

I have created `AsyncTask` to `ping` or `heartbeat` the `server` and call this task every second using `Timer` in my `MainActivity`.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
      new connectTaskMain().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of data being exchanged and without the TCP keep-alive option set on  the socket, a socket will be unaware that the remote connection suddenly disappeared.  This isn't anything new, it's been a well known socket design problem.

The general pattern is to have some sort of keep alive or ping protocol on the socket that sends a "I'm still here" message between client and server so both endpoints know the other side hasn't gone away.  When an endpoint goes offline, the remote socket will fail on a subsequent recv\send call (or throw an exception).  Thereby the application or server can handle the disconnect as it sees fit. But this presents an interesting challenge on mobile - frequent network messages may drain the battery by keeping the radio on.

Mobile devices, including Android, typically don't keep long running socket connections to services.  Instead, the client will "connect on demand" and close the socket when it's done.  Similarly, if the server needs to send something to the device, it typically makes use of the platform's "push" notification service.  On Android, the current push notification service is [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).  The client registers with FCM and the server.  When the server has something new to give to the client, it sends a push notification through FCM.  The client app in turn, gets the notification message as a wakeup that something new is available, and then reconnects to the server to get the actual message. The best example of this is email on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You can send `ping` packets to check if the server is alive.

Comment: But where? as I am on the MainActivity of the application.

Comment: I don't know android but maybe you can fire some thread which checks your server every xxx seconds or something like that.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443166/android-how-to-check-if-the-server-is-available