# server availability checker in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to check internet connection of device first, if Internet is available...I need to check server is online or not. I have searched lot of in stackflow for it but there no where latest solution is available like below

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443166/android-how-to-check-if-the-server-is-available)

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443166/android-how-to-check-if-the-server-is-available)

but none of it is working properly as people comments and my trial. I am checking internet status of device with below code

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    boolean isActiveNetworkConnected = false;

    if (connectivity != null) {

        NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info != null) {
            if (info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                isActiveNetworkConnected = true;
            } else {
                isActiveNetworkConnected = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        isActiveNetworkConnected = false;
    }

    return isActiveNetworkConnected;
}
```

Let me know anyone have proper solution which can check server available or not with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the internet connectivity, you can simply make a test API hit to check server status. Send the request to server if server respond ok, start next work or in-other case handle server not responding message for user.

Here is a sample using `okhttp`

```
public boolean isServerUp(){

    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

      public void run() throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("your server url here")
            .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
          @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
          }

          @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            return true; 
          }
        });
      }
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking the current status of the server after network checked, need to check if the response is not null